# how to protect an ID in the url with php?

Tags: php, file, security, url, get

For a simple mailinglist, i use flat-file (.txt) files for storing the date from subscribers.
The name of the `.txt` files is the same as the `id` i assign to a subscriber.
A .txt file with the data inside (name and email) looks so something like this:
`id-8759874589.txt`
In every email i send, i send an unsubscribe link so that the subscriber can unsubscribe from receiving mails. I encode the unsubscribe link with `base64_encode`. Only for the mask of the eye.
An unsubscribe-link looks something like this:

```
http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?id=aWQtMjAxOTEyMjMNDUyMTQ%3D&email=amNtZy5tYWVzc2VuQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ%3D%3D
```

For unsubscribing, i use this code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    // decode the id and email string
    $id_decode = base64_decode($id);
    $email_decode = base64_decode($email);
    if( isset($id_decode) ) {   

        $filename = 'subscribers/'.$id_decode.'.txt';   
        // delete subscribers entry
        if(file_exists($filename)) { 
            unlink($filename);  
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><b>'.$email_decode.'</b> is successfully removed from our mailinglist!</div>';       
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Email not found or you already have unsubscribed from our mailinglist!</div>';
        }       
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see: the `id`, which is assigned to the .txt file, will be unlinked. The subscriber is deleted from the mailinglist.

**My worries:**
Lets say: you were a subscriber and you did unsubscribe, then you know how the url is created. 
You can start guessing: How will the subscriber be unsubscribed? Lets say: you know that every subscriber has his data in a .txt file with the name of the id. You can let a robot guess the identities in the url string and execute this url. In **worse case scenario**, he found an id that really exists and the file will be deleted. A random subscriber is removed from the list without doing itself.

How can i protect this better?

Comment: Make the random codes complex enough as to be basically unguessable. A UUID works.

Comment: *"How can i protect this better?"* - Use a database if at all possible. What you have now can be very dangerous, should it ever fall into the wrong hands. Plus, text files are a LOT of work. I know this firsthand. Any special reason you're not using a database for this?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner The reason is: i want to create a simple mailing-list without using a database. Of course i can use a database, but i see it as a challenge to make it very simple with `.txt` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique code and store this code **in** the file, also provide this code in unsubscribe url:

```
http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?id=aWQtMjAxOTEyMjMNDUyMTQ%3D&email=amNtZy5tYWVzc2VuQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ%3D%3D&token=WHATEVER
```

In this case you can also get a token from url as `$_GET['token']` and check if it is the same as one in the file. If it is the same (and no one **except you** knows the algorithm with which token is created) - you can unsubscribe the user. In case of failure you can consider that someone is cheating)

Answer (score 0):

You should worry when you only encode your parameters.

As you already expected gives Base64 no security, also the fact that you expect an Id and a email gives information to hack you.

The third risk is your response, there you als give information away, just inform your that the request is processed.

You should use encryption [see](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string/) to be safe.